# Error: Element type is invalid expected a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working with ReactJS.

I could not figure out where the problem is.

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
Check the render method of `App`.

```
const App=()=>{
      const Person=[
         {name:"Liya",age:4},
         {name:"kuru", age:7},
         {name:"belaynesh",age:56}
          ]
    const [currentstate,setStateFn]=useState({Person:Person})
    const incrementAge=()=>{
      let copyOfPerson=[...currentstate.Person];//copy of the person array
        let newstate=copyOfPerson.Person.map((per)=>{
          return {name:per.name,age:per.age+1}
        })
        console.log(newstate)
        setStateFn(newstate)
    }
    return(
      <div>
        {
         currentstate.Person.map((per,index)=>{
           return <Person key={index} name={per.name} age={per.age}></Person>
         })
        }
         <button onClick={()=>{incrementAge()}}>IncrementAge</button>
      </div>

    )
    }
    export default App;
```

The error is:

```
 import App from './App';
   5 | import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
   6 | 
>  7 | ReactDOM.render(
   8 |   <React.StrictMode>
   9 |     <App />
  10 |   </React.StrictMode>,
```

Comment: What is your class Person?

Answer (score 0):

You defined the `Person` as **an array** of constant data.

But you used it in your functional component's return as a **JSX component**, which caused the error you mentioned.

---

You can make the `Person` component like below

```
const Personal = ({name, age}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {name}, {age}
    </div>
  )
}

return <Personal key={index} name={per.name} age={per.age} />;
```

[image]

[image: Edit zealous-babbage-g8lbn]

Answer (score 0):

In your return statement, you have got

```
return(
      <div>
        {
         currentstate.Person.map((per,index)=>{
           return <Person key={index} name={per.name} age={per.age}></Person>
         })
        }
         <button onClick={()=>{incrementAge()}}>IncrementAge</button>
      </div>

    )
```

For the following line,

```
return <Person key={index} name={per.name} age={per.age}></Person>
```

Person is defined earlier as an **array**, but here you are trying to render it as a **react component**, hence React compiler is complaining.